# Run shell command as root in system service AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I'm customizing `AOSP`. I have `system service`, which starts by `SystemServer` with other `system services`. I will execute some commands in shell from my `service`. 
I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` - this works fine if commands does not require root permissions. My system service has "system" rights, not "root" (it is logical). I'm trying to execute commands with `"su -c"` prefix (ex. - `"su -c mkdir /mnt/sdcard/NewFolder"`), without success.

Question: how to execute shell commands as root? (*su binary is included in build*). Should I create service which runs with root rights, not with system rights (if it is possible!)

**EDIT:** I don't need SuperUser.apk, just su binary (possible busybox for additional functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error do you get?
May be you need to modify system/extras/su/su.c:

```
/* Until we have something better, only root and the shell can use su. */
myuid = getuid();
if (myuid != AID_ROOT && myuid != AID_SHELL && myuid != AID_SYSTEM) {
    fprintf(stderr,"su: uid %d not allowed to su\n", myuid);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: what can I change in system/extras/su/su.c for working my su binary from system service?

Comment: should I simply delete that "if" ?

Comment: That will be unsecure. Better to add "myuid != AID_SYSTEM" statement.
Original su.c has only two conditions - "myuid != AID_ROOT && myuid != AID_SHELL"

Comment: is it possible to add root permissions to "su" binary in Android file system? It will be enough for running su from system service? Now "su" binary has "root shell" rights, what will be if I change them on "root root"?

Comment: The su binary already has "root permission" (a setuid bit and ownership by root), but the logic of the program is set to refuse to work if started by any but the listed allowed original uid's.  Typical "rooted" installations augment that check with logic to check against some whitelist of allowed app users and/or popup a user configuration dialog.

Comment: Yeah, that is. But still not working - can't execute "su -c 'command_name'". I'm trying this from my system service, which has system rights, and in "su.c" file I added "myuid != AID_SYSTEM" in 'if' statement. Logical this allows to processes with 'system' rights execute su binary.