# How to modify AOSP to allow specific apps to get root access in Android 9?

Tags: linux-kernel, android-source, android-9.0-pie, su, rooted-device

I am working on the AOSP project in Android 9, i have to give root access of my system app to run the Specific Shell/ADB commands like dumpsys, dpm, etc, which need Super User permission.

I took references from [Run shell command as root in system service AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611922/run-shell-command-as-root-in-system-service-aosp) but this is for old Android OS, and in the su.c and android_filesystem_config.h files contents are totally changed.

Please provide guidance.